# xcode 4 organizer iPad 2 screenshot is rotated

Tags: xcode, ipad, screenshot, organizer

When I try to take the snapshot in any portrait/landscape mode , it comes inverted, (Rotated to 180 degree).

I tried to find the settings everywhere but couldn't find it.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today and when I found no other answers and only your question, I decided I had to try to figure it out on my own (BTW - nothing in Apple Dev forums either).

I found that my device was rotated to Landscape before I started my app and my app locks the orientation to Portrait by overloading the shouldRotateOnOrientationChange and returning YES when orientation == Portrait.

**I exited my app, rotated my iPad to Landscape and back to Portrait.  Then started my app.  When I went to get the screenshot it was correct.**

I am suspecting that the original state is in the debugger / XCode and is not updated, therefore, the Organizer sees a static setting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply above. Unlock the device orientation lock (Hardware switch near volume buttons) solved my problem. Maybe it helps someone.

Comment: FYI - that is a configurable button in Settings.  I have mine configured for speaker mute, so it might not explain my experience unless it is set to device orientation lock.